# How to split string on substrings determined by function p5.js

Tags: string, split, p5.js

I managed to find all n-digit sequence that repeat in a given digit string. Though my problem is how do i split the string on the repeated sequences, as shown on this example:

string `123543512`

searching for `2`-digit sequences

duplicates `"12","35"`

splitedstring `12 35 4 35 12`

```
    var n = 2; 
    var a = 0;
    var b = n;
    var arr =[];

    function newText(input) {
      var str1 = textfield.value(); //given string
      while (a <= str1.length & b < str1.length+1) { 
        res = str1.substring(b, a);
        arr[a]=res;
        push();
        a = a + 1
        b = b + 1
      }         
        var potnij = arr.slice().sort();
        var takisam = []; //duplicates
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (potnij[i + 1] == potnij[i]) {
                takisam.push(potnij[i]);
            }
        }
        console.log(takisam);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first stop should be [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).

Specifically, [the `splitTokens()` function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/splitTokens) does exactly what you describe. You give it a string and then a list of tokens (substrings) to split on, and it returns an array of strings that were separated by those tokens.

Comment: `dziel = splitTokens(str1, takisam);` I made this, and it returns me the array of digits sequences that weren't duplicated. Which is good, but how i am able then to know the exact position at where it got split? 
In other way how i would be able to physically put " "(space) in my string in between the duplicates and the digits that aren't duplicated?

btw. Thanks for the support man, im really new to this, and it is really hard to learn all of this :D, but im happy i progressed in my problem

Comment: Well, splitting a string is a specific thing, which is accomplished by the `split()` or `splitTokens()` functions. But it sounds like you actually want something else, not string splitting. Again, think about how you'd do this by hand. There are several string functions that might help you: you could find the index of each duplicated sequence, and then call the `substring()` function to extract the different parts of the string in order to build a new string that contains your spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all sequences like this(Just a rough example)

```
const sequence = (str, len) => {
    return str.split('').reduce((acc, current) => {
        const last = acc[acc.length - 1];
        if (last) {
            const biggest = parseInt(last.slice(-1));
            if (current > biggest && last.length < (len || 2)) {
                acc.splice(-1, 1, "" + last + current);
                return acc
            }
        }
        acc.push(current);
        return acc;
    }, []);
};
```

You may add data validation and other checks if needed. Then you can use another function to remove duplicates.
Please check a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5vy6k4hp/3/